TCP server & client process NOT able to communicate over listening port when called from perl script
I am using Perl script on linux system that performs followings

Starts TCP Server process on a localhost with a listening port (say 4000). Process finds and allocates a free port as listening one
Thereafter, Starts TCP Client process  to communicate to server over port on the same host
"A.exe -host IP-address:4000"

The client process is not able to connect to Server. It waits forever and finally times out. I tried followings but nothing worked
Different port values 4000,4004, 4321 etc.
Invoking the client process using 'A.exe -host IP-address:4000' or system("A.exe -host IP-address:4000") from Perl script.
I checked the followings as well

ss -tulnp | grep 4000 -> shows port is in listening mode for Server process

2.. telnet IP-address 4000  -> it able to connect

No other process using 4000 port

But below method works even though it takes 15-20 mins just to establish the connection b/w server and client process

Starts TCP Server process on a localhost with a listening port (say, 4000 or any other port)

Start manually TCP client process on separate terminal on same host


Any suggestion what could go wrong within the script that preventing the connection between TCP Server and Client process?

There is nothing obvious wrong with what you describe as doing. So it is probably something wrong with what you are actually doing, which might be different from what you describe or (more likely) there might be important details which you don't mention. So please provide sufficient details so that other can reproduce your problem, i.e. create a [mcve].
